# Handle hash (#) in query string

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I try create simple OAuthHandler.
After my request (using the [implicit flow](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user)), server send request to my page, with an authorization code. But in query string from server, all parameters starts with hash (#) instead?

In method HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync, I'm trying to parse query string, but none of the properties contain authorization code or anything like that.

How can I handle hash in query string?

Comment: A # is not part of a query string ever, it's a document fragment, it can only come after the query string, not in it. What server is sending what? Show the URL?

Comment: Anything after and including the hash won't even be passed to your server. You need to URL encode it first.

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user

Comment: http://REDIRECT_URI#access_token= 533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3&expires_in=86400&user_id=8492&state=123456

Comment: This is service that a want use

Answer (score 0):

As Joppe and David mentioned in the comments, anything after the hash (#) is part of the fragment, and is **not** sent to the server by the browser. That's why your server code can't see it.

The implicit flow is for JavaScript clients, not web servers. You want the [authorization code flow](https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user) instead.  The redirect will look like:

```
REDIRECT_URI?code=7a6fa...
```

Since the code is transmitted in the query string, instead of the fragment, your server-side code will be able to see it.